# Java playing audio using different sampling rate

Tags: java

I have to sets of voice data. When user inputs text, my program finds the words from the text and searches for a word in a directory. If found, it plays the word immediately. Otherwise it plays from another directory which contains the diphones of the word, using diphone rules. To match both voices, I have to use different sampling rates i.e. 88100.0 for the first directory and 44100.0 for the second. Now, sometimes the words with higher sampling rate gets played first even though they were next to the word which used lower sampling rate. How do I tell the higher sampling rate word to wait until the lower one finishes playing? I'm using java SourceDataLine to play audio.

Comment: drain the line before continuing.

Comment: How are you playing the audio?  If you are opening one file at a time, then `drain` should work unless you create a thread each time you play audio.  Otherwise, if you simply add the frames to the `SourceDataLine` then they should play in order...the only issue is converting the sampling rate (you can't just mix frames in a single source data line with audio having differing sampling rates).

Comment: I'm creating new threads each time I'm playing a word

Comment: Is there a reason to do that?  It seems like if you want to play each word, one after the other, that using parallel threads doesn't make sense.

Comment: I solved the problem, I used only one thread. Thanks for pointing me towards the thread problem @Jared